# Spring Data/hibernate Updating child DTO object and @MapsId

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I am getting an EntityExistException when I try and update the Parent and the Child is a DTO. How do I go about fixing this? I've tried calling merge on Parent, with no luck. I am using Spring data jpa and hibernate.

```
@Entity
class Parent {
    @Id
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parent")
    private Child child;

    // getters and setters
}

@Entity
class Child {
    @Id
    private int id;

    private String data;

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne
    private Parent parent;

    // getters and setters
}
```

In my rest service I am doing the following:

```
Child child = new Child(data); // data from request
Parent parent = parentRepositoryService.getParent(id);
parent.setChild(child);
parentRepositoryService.update(parent);
```

parentRepositoryService.class

```
class ParentRepositoryService {
    public void update(Parent parent) {
        parent.getChild().setParent(parent);  // necessary to prevent Exception
        parentRepository.save(parent);
    }
}
```

I think the problem is that the Child object is already in the session from the "parentRepositoryService.getParent(id)" call. Then the Child object is created outside the session causing a mismatch between the old and new Child object. I'd prefer to not have to manually update the session based Child object from the request data, and would like to just execute an equivalent to  mysql "insert... on duplicate key update" for the Child entity.

Answer (score 0):

I think here is what happens:

You load a parent `P` which has a child `C1`. So you have now the following objects:

```
P -> C1
C1 -> P
```

Where the arrow means references.

Now you create a new child `C2` and set it as child of `P` and end up with the following objects in:

```
P -> C2
C1 -> P
C2 -> P
```

Note that `C1` still references `P`. When the session gets flushed, Hibernate uses the references in the children to persist the relationship, and you get an exception, because `P` is referenced by two children.

In order to fix it, unset the reference from the old child to the parent, you might even want to delete it. This should really happen inside the `Parent` class, just as the

```
parent.getChild().setParent(parent)
```

should be part of `Parent.setChild`

Comment: how do you recommend removing the reference from the old child to the parent? I tried to call oldChild.setParent(null) and still got an exception.  "EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session"

Comment: I think this is happening because C1 & C2 are using the same PK (Parent.id), but are different objects.

Comment: Yes, probably due to shared PK between Parent and Child. One solution would be to update the existing Child in response to the rest request.